# How to retrieve rows that has the maximum row number for a customer?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

Highlighted rows has the maximum row number for a customer.
How to get output report with only the rows that are highlighted??

select name, order id, date,
(ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY name,order id ORDER BY date)) as rn
from table;

Comment: Hi all, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a subquery or a CTE:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  select name, order_id, date, (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY name,order id 
  ORDER BY date)) as rn from table),
last_entry AS (SELECT name, max(rn) AS rn FROM d GROUP BY name)
SELECT data.*
FROM data JOIN last_entry
  ON last_entry.name = data.name
    AND last_entry.rn = data.rn;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I want the highest row number for each customer A,B,C etc.,